# How can I check a variable is local or global in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

When executing a JavaScript function, how can I decide the used variable is local or global?

Because I only want to record the modification to the global variable.

```
<script>
   var a;
   a =4;

   function foo(){
       var a =3;
   }()

</script>
```

when executing the above code, I only want to record the a=4, not a=3;

Comment: I'm don't think you can access variables with the same name out of the scope like you want. Solution: use unique names if you need to access both.

Comment: `window.a` should reference the global variable, but I've never done this (re-using the same variable name in different scopes) so I don't know about the potential caveats.

Comment: I want to instrument the javascript codes to only record the modification to the global variable. THe above code is just an example.

Answer (score 7):

```
<script>
  var a;
  a = 4;
  function foo(){
    // version 1:
    if (window.hasOwnProperty('a')){
      // "global" a exists
    }
    // version 2:
    if (typeof window.a !== 'undefined'){
      // "global" a exists and is defined
    }
  }();
</script>
```

Something like that?

Comment: Typeof only tells you the type, not whether it "exists" or not. The `in` operator is for that.

Comment: Well, IMHO existing is defined by if a variable is defined or not. But I guess you could use `window.hasOwnProperty('a')` or `a in window`.

Comment: Precsisely. [so limit]

Comment: This should work in most cases, but if `typeof window.a === 'undefined'` it can mean that it was defined, but holds the `undefined` value.

Comment: Or has been declared and not assigned any value.

Answer (score 3):

Global variables are added as properties of the global object, which is *window* in a browser. To test if an object has a property or not, use the `in` operator:

```
// In global scope
var bar;

function foo() {
  if (bar in window) {
    // bar is a property of window
  } else {
    // bar isn't a property of window
  }
}
```

For more general code, the environment may not have a *window* object, so:

```
// In global scope
var global = this;

function foo() {
  if (bar in global) {
    // bar is a property of the global object
  } else {
    // bar isn't a property of the global object
  }
}
```

Beware of *typeof* tests. They only tell you the type of the variable's value and return *undefined* if either the property doesn't exist **or** its value has been set to *undefined*.

Answer (score 0):

I was looking for the same thing. When I couldn't find an answer, I ended up coming up with this:

```
<script>
    var a;
    a = {prop1: 'global object'};

    (function foo() {

        var a = {prop1: 'local object'};

        var isLocal = true;
        if (window.hasOwnProperty('a')) {
            if(Object.is(a, window['a'])) {
                isLocal = false;
            }
        }
    })();

</script>
```

If variable `a` is a primitive value, then `Object.is()` will always return true, so you'd need some other way to deal with them.